# Gantt chart view in web part

Tags: xml, list, sharepoint, view, gantt-chart

I'm trying to display a Gantt chart view in a web part.

First I just want to make sure I had the correct XML for the Gantt chart view. So I created the Gantt chart from the schema list. This worked fine. Then I tried to copy this XML in a web part. But now I don't get a Gantt chart view I just get a normal list view.

This is the XML for the Gantt chart view:

```
<WebPartPages:WebPartZone runat="server" FrameType="None" ID="Main" Title="loc:Main">
                <ZoneTemplate>
                    <WebPartPages:XsltListViewWebPart ID="XsltListViewWebPart" runat="server" Description="" ListDisplayName="Strategic Items" PartOrder="0" HelpLink="" AllowRemove="True" IsVisible="True" AllowHide="True" UseSQLDataSourcePaging="True" ExportControlledProperties="False" IsIncludedFilter="" DataSourceID="" Title="My Strategic Items" ViewFlag="8388621" NoDefaultStyle="" AllowConnect="True" FrameState="Normal" CatalogIconImageUrl="/_layouts/images/itgen.png" PageSize="-1" PartImageLarge="/_layouts/images/itgen.png" AsyncRefresh="False" Dir="Default" DetailLink="/Lists/StrategicItems" ShowWithSampleData="False" FrameType="Default" PartImageSmall="" IsIncluded="True" SuppressWebPartChrome="False" AllowEdit="True" AutoRefresh="False" AutoRefreshInterval="60" AllowMinimize="True" WebId="00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000" ViewContentTypeId="" InitialAsyncDataFetch="False" GhostedXslLink="main.xsl" MissingAssembly="Cannot import this Web Part." HelpMode="Modeless"  AllowZoneChange="True" ManualRefresh="False" __MarkupType="vsattributemarkup"  __AllowXSLTEditing="true" WebPart="true" Height="">
                        <XmlDefinition>
                            <View BaseViewID="1" Type="GANTT" WebPartZoneID="Main" DisplayName="Gantt View" DefaultView="TRUE" MobileView="FALSE" MobileDefaultView="FALSE" SetupPath="pages\viewpage.aspx" ImageUrl="/_layouts/images/generic.png" Url="GanttView.aspx">
                                <ViewFields>
                                    <FieldRef Name="Icon" />
                                    <FieldRef Name="LinkTitle" />
                                    <FieldRef Name="Item Type" />
                                    <FieldRef Name="Responsible Business" />
                                    <FieldRef Name="AssignedTo" />
                                    <FieldRef Name="Progress Status" />
                                    <FieldRef Name="DMTargetDate" />
                                    <FieldRef Name="% Complete" />
                                </ViewFields>
                                <ViewData>
                                    <FieldRef Name="DMStartDate" Type="GanttStartDate" />
                                    <FieldRef Name="DMTargetDate" Type="GanttEndDate" />
                                    <FieldRef Name="Title" Type="GanttTitle" />
                                    <FieldRef Name="% Complete" Type="GanttPercentComplete" />
                                </ViewData>
                                <Query />
                                <!--<Aggregations Value="Off" />-->
                                <RowLimit Paged="TRUE">30</RowLimit>
                                <!--<Mobile MobileItemLimit="99" />-->
                                <Toolbar Type="Standard" />
                                <!--<XslLink Default="TRUE">main.xsl</XslLink>-->
                                <ParameterBindings>
                                    <ParameterBinding Name="NoAnnouncements" Location="Resource(wss,noXinviewofY_LIST)" />
                                    <ParameterBinding Name="NoAnnouncementsHowTo" Location="Resource(wss,noXinviewofY_DEFAULT)" />
                                </ParameterBindings>
                            </View>
                        </XmlDefinition>
                    </WebPartPages:XsltListViewWebPart>
                </ZoneTemplate>
            </WebPartPages:WebPartZone>
```

Does anyone know why it just displays a normal list view and not a Gantt chart view?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Please use the List View Web Part, specifying Gantt View as the view to display.

Do not copy the XML in another web part, it will not work.

Answer (score 0):

> Please use the List View Web Part, specifying Gantt View as the view to display.

Gantt view is not an option when creating a View off of an External List.  Is there another way around this hurdle?

Answer (score 0):

I want this too because I want to display the gantt in the hours scale instead of days. There probably is indeed an XML/XSL view capability, so long as web parts have the ability to view list data.